# Ruby: remove from the string

Tags: ruby

I have the URL `http://localhost:3000/en/invest_offers?utf8=blahblahblah`. How can I get `?utf8=blahblahblah` part of the URL? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`URI::parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse), [`URI::Generic#query`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#query):

```
require 'uri'

url = 'http://localhost:3000/en/invest_offers?utf8=blahblahblah'
URI.parse(url)
# => #<URI::HTTP:0x0000000213aae0 URL:http://localhost:3000/en/invest_offers?utf8=blahblahblah>
URI.parse(url).query
# => "utf8=blahblahblah"
```

Answer (score 6):

Do as below using [`URI::Generic.query`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#query):

```
require 'uri'

URI("http://localhost:3000/en/invest_offers?utf8=blahblahblah").query
# => "utf8=blahblahblah"
```

Comment: You can find the query attribute [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#query).

Comment: @falsetru Thanks I was able to see, but didn't get the link from the doc, how did you get it? Still I am searching :)

Comment: I examined the `name` attribute of the element.

Comment: @falsetru I am talking about the official link, that link was not found by me, but I was seeing it as mentioned in the document, but the link I wasn't getting to give in my answer.

Comment: That link is not in the TOC (left side menu). I examined it using `inspect element` feature of the browser.

Comment: @falsetru Great job +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:--

```
require 'uri'
url = 'http://localhost:3000/en/invest_offers?utf8=blahblahblah'
parsed_url = URI.parse(url)
```

if you just want to get string query part like `"utf8=blahblahblah"`
you should do

```
parsed_url.query
```

if you want get `"blahblahblah"`,
you should just do

```
params["utf8"]
```

or else

```
p = CGI.parse(parsed_url.query)
# p is now {"utf8"=>["blahblahblah"]}
p["utf8"].first 
#=> "blahblahblah"
```